# Using .gitconfig and .gitattributes of a submodule

Tags: git, attributes, config, git-submodules

in my git repo **A** I am using a submodule (**B**), which comes with a .gitattributes and a .gitconfig. Those basically set a git filter for .vcxproj files (.gitattributes) and 'implementing' the it (.gitconfig).

When I am in the repository **B** itself the .gitattribute/.gitconfig setup works find.
I enabled it via

```
git config --local input.path ../.gitconfig
```

But how can I *activate* those filters when I am in the repository **A** and have **B** as submodule in A?

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work finally.

I found that the *normal* config file of a git repository for submodules reside in the parent repos **.git/modules/submodule/path/**.

So, if you want to reference the submodule's .gitconfig you have to do this relative to **this** config file.

However, this is tedious to do for several submodules which .gitattributes and .gitconfig files have the same content (as it was in my case). So I went with writing the filter definition directly from the command line:

```
git submodule foreach git config --local filter.my_filter.clean "<filter_command>"
```

This line will go into an after_clone_script together with other stuff that has to be done.